# sed append comma to each line, except the last line in the block

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am writing a utility script to fix a Verilog code using `sed`. What I'm trying to do is converting code as follows

input file

```
my_instance_name
(
   .port1     (port1    )
   .port2     (port2    ) // comment for port line 2
   .port3     (port3    )
   .port4     (port4    ) // comment for port line 4
);
```

What I want

```
my_instance_name 
(
   .port1     (port1    ),
   .port2     (port2    ), // comment for port line 2
   .port3     (port3    ), 
   .port4     (port4    ) // comment for port line 4
);
```

The points are

1. Append comma just after the closing parenthesis of each 'port' lines
2. Do not append comma for the last 'port'
3. Preserve the comments if exist (comment starts with double-slash like C)
4. Whitespaces (except the line breaks) are not important. it is only for human readability.
5. There can be multiple linebreaks after the last port line

If the `sed` script becomes too complicated, it is also OK to just prepend the comma just before the dot, except the first port line. i.e, the following code is OK although it is not pretty.

```
my_instance_name 
(
   .port1     (port1    )
   ,.port2     (port2    ) // comment for port line 2
   ,.port3     (port3    )
   ,.port4     (port4    ) // comment for port line 4
);
```

I could only manage appending commas to all 'port' lines via the following two line

```
sed -i /^\s*my_instance_name.*/,/);/{s/^\(\s*\..*)\)\(\s*\/\/.*\)/\1,\2/} my_verilog.txt
sed -i /^\s*my_instance_name.*/,/);/{s/^\(\s*\..*)\)\s*\$/\1,/} my_verilog.txt
```

It detects the code scope from "my_instance_name" to ");". The first line insert comma between the closing parenthesis and comment. The second line is for port lines without comments.

But I have no idea how to exclude the last line.

Comment: "Whitespace is not important". Are you sure?  I suspect you cannot just delete all the newline characters, since they are being used to terminate comments.  You mean that whitespace other than newlines are not important. (I think)

Comment: @WilliamPursell You are correct. The line breaks matter. I edited the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `gnu-awk` solution using custom `RS` to split shown block on header and footer:

```bash
awk -i inplace -v RS='my_instance_name\\s*\\(\\s*' '
NF {
   $0 = gensub(/(\n\s*)([^)])/, "\\1,\\2", "g")
}
{ORS=RT} 1' file

cat file

my_instance_name
(
   .port1     (port1    )
   ,.port2     (port2    ) // comment for port line 2
   ,.port3     (port3    )
   ,.port4     (port4    ) // comment for port line 4
);
```

Note that due to use of `-i inplace` changes will be saved inline in same input file.

**Breakdown:**

- `-v RS='my_instance_name\\s*\\(\\s*'` splits input data by `my_instance_name` followed by 0 or more whitespaces then `(` and again followed by 0 or more whitespaces.
- `gensub` function matches newline followed by 0 or more whitespaces and captures in a group #1. It matches any character that's not `)` (to avoid matching `);` line) and captures in a group #2. In replacement we insert a comma between these 2 values.
- `{ORS=RT}` populates `ORS` same as the text matched by `RS` pattern i.e. `RT`
- `1` prints all records

---

For appending commas in the end use similar awk:

```bash
awk -v RS='my_instance_name\\s*\\(\\s*' '
NF {
   $0 = gensub(/\)([^\n]*\n[^)])/, "),\\1", "g")
}
{ORS=RT} 1' file

my_instance_name
(
   .port1     (port1    ),
   .port2     (port2    ), // comment for port line 2
   .port3     (port3    ),
   .port4     (port4    ) // comment for port line 4
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This would probably be significantly easier in Awk.

```
awk '/my_instance_name/ { p=1 }
  p && /\);/ { if (prev) print prev; print; p=0; next }
  p && /port/ { if (prev) { sub(/\)/, "),", prev); print prev; }
    prev = $0; next } 1' my_verilog.txt
```

Standard Awk does not have an option like the `-i` option of `sed`; this will simply print the output to standard output, which you can redirect to a temporary file and then move back on top of the original. Or if you have GNU Awk, it has `-i inplace` which works like `sed`'s `-i`.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -Ezi.bak 's/\([^)]*\)/&,/g;s/(\([^)]*\)),([^\n]*\n\);)/\1\2/g' input_file
my_instance_name
(
   .port1     (port1    ),
   .port2     (port2    ), // comment for port line 2
   .port3     (port3    ),
   .port4     (port4    ) // comment for port line 4
);
```